# Принцип работы Array.prototype.concat()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Для скрипта в Adobe Photoshop, есть диалоговое окно с элементами выбора и управления:

```
var dlg = new Window('dialog{text: "Выбор размеров", bounds: [' + fBounds(150,200,370,150) + '], \
            panel_s: Panel{text: "Стандартные:", bounds: [' + fBounds(5,5,203,85) + '], \
                checkbox_16:  Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(5,13,55,14) + '],   text: "16 x 16"},   \
                checkbox_24:  Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(5,33,55,14) + '],   text: "24 x 24"},   \
                checkbox_32:  Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(5,53,55,14) + '],   text: "32 x 32"},   \
                checkbox_48:  Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(67,13,55,14) + '],  text: "48 x 48"},   \
                checkbox_64:  Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(67,33,55,14) + '],  text: "64 x 64"},   \
                checkbox_96:  Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(67,53,55,14) + '],  text: "96 x 96"},   \
                checkbox_128: Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(129,13,65,14) + '], text: "128 x 128"}, \
                checkbox_256: Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(129,33,65,14) + '], text: "256 x 256"}, \
                checkbox_512: Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(129,53,65,14) + '], text: "512 x 512"}  \
            }, \
            panel_o: Panel{text: "Другие:", bounds: [' + fBounds(206,5,69,64) + '],\
                checkbox_19: Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(5,13,55,14) + '], text: "19 x 19"}, \
                checkbox_38: Checkbox{bounds: [' + fBounds(5,33,55,14) + '], text: "38 x 38"}  \
            }, \
            panel_u: Panel{text: "Свои:", bounds: [' + fBounds(273,5,92,85) + '],\
                checkbox_u1: Checkbox{bounds:   [' + fBounds(5,13,14,14) + ']},                                                 \
                static_u1:   StaticText{bounds: [' + fBounds(21,13,31,14) + '], text: ". . . x", justify: "right"},             \
                edittext_u1: EditText{bounds:   [' + fBounds(53,11,30,19) + '], text: ". . .", properties: {multiline: false}}, \
                \
                checkbox_u2: Checkbox{bounds:   [' + fBounds(5,33,14,14) + ']},                                                 \
                static_u2:   StaticText{bounds: [' + fBounds(21,33,31,14) + '], text: ". . . x", justify: "right"},             \
                edittext_u2: EditText{bounds:   [' + fBounds(53,31,30,19) + '], text: ". . .", properties: {multiline: false}}, \
                \
                checkbox_u3: Checkbox{bounds:   [' + fBounds(5,53,14,14) + ']},                                                 \
                static_u3:   StaticText{bounds: [' + fBounds(21,53,31,14) + '], text: ". . . x", justify: "right"},             \
                edittext_u3: EditText{bounds:   [' + fBounds(53,51,30,19) + '], text: ". . .", properties: {multiline: false}}  \
            }, \
            button_all:    Button{bounds:       [' + fBounds(208,70,64,19) + '], text: "Все"},          \
            static_save:   StaticText{bounds:   [' + fBounds(5,99,75,14) + '],   text: "Сохранить в:"}, \
            drop_save:     DropDownList{bounds: [' + fBounds(78,95,287,23) + '], properties: {items: ["папку рядом с исходным файлом", "-", "Выбрать папку..."]}, helpTip:"Ooops!!!"}, \
            progress_save: Progressbar{bounds:  [' + fBounds(0,0,370,4) + '],    value:50},             \
            button_run:    Button{bounds:       [' + fBounds(4,122,70,22) + '],  text: "Создать"}       \
        };'
    );

    // -- Выбор всех значений

    dlg.show();
```

Есть обработчик кнопки, для выбора всех чекбоксов:

```
// -- Выбор всех значений
dlg.button_all.addEventListener('click', function() {

    alert(dlg.panel_s.children + '\r\n' + dlg.panel_s.children.length);
    // Коллекция (9 элементов) и количество (9) отображаются верно

    alert(dlg.panel_o.children + '\r\n' + dlg.panel_o.children.length);
    // Коллекция (2 элемента) и количество (2) отображаются верно

    // Объединяем обе коллекции и три отдельных элемента
    var aPanel = [].concat(
        dlg.panel_s.children, 
        dlg.panel_o.children, 
        dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u1, 
        dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u2, 
        dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u3
    );

    alert(aPanel + '\r\n' + aPanel.length);
    // Массив отображается верно (14 элементов), но количество не совпадает (5) !
});
```

Из комментариев в коде обработчика видно, где возникает проблема, и вопрос следующий...
Метод **Array.prototype.concat()**, согласно [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), должен объединять массивы, раскрывая их до первого уровня вложенности. Собственно, так и происходит, если верить последнему всплывающему окну (см. код обработчика) - там отображаются все элементы в порядке добавления.
Но, при обращении к `aPanel[0]`, возвращается не первый элемент (`checkbox_16`), а вся коллекция `dlg.panel_s.children` . Соответственно при этом, длина массива `aPanel` составляет 5, а добраться до нужного элемента можно только указав вложенность в коллекции, т.е. `aPanel[0][0]` .
Это баг или хитрая логика? И как правильно объединить массивы с помощью **concat()** ?

Comment: С очередной, набранной высотой вас! (+5000)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо ))

Comment: А сообщения из чата не долетают? Бывает, когда долго не заходишь

Comment: @Alexandr_TT не долетают :( Не знал про такое...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Поправочка

Действительно, согласно [справке MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> Метод `concat` создаёт новый массив, состоящий из элементов в объекте,
>   на котором он был вызван, за которыми по порядку следуют, для каждого
>   аргумента, все его элементы (если аргумент является массивом), либо
>   сам аргумент (если он массивом не является)

Только вот про `первый уровень вложенности`, как видите, тут ни слова.
Вот Вам наглядный пример:

```js
let x = [].concat(1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6, [7, 8]]);
console.log(x);        // Выведем полученный массив
console.log(x.length); // Длина равняется не 8, как если бы все раскрывалось 
                       // до первого уровня вложенности, а 7!
console.log(x[6]);     // 6-ой элемент является массивом
```

Однако это не отменяет Вашей проблемы, так как в Вашем случае, если бы элементы `dlg.{foo}.children` были массивами, то их *разворачивание* все равно бы произошло

---

### Так в чем же дело?

Не буду Вас томить и наконец скажу, в чем же проблема. Еще раз обратите внимание на строчку:

> если аргумент является массивом

К чему я клоню? Указанные Вами элементы **не являются массивами**! Да, они являются коллекциями и подобны массивам, но все же спецификация строга.

Давайте посмотрим, как метод `concat` ведет себя с [объектом arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), который, как и Ваши элементы, является по сути коллекцией, но не массивом:

```js
function test() {
    console.log(Array.isArray(arguments)); // false
    return [].concat(arguments, arguments);
}

console.log(test(1, 2, 3).toString()); // [object Arguments], [object Arguments]
```

Как видите, `concat` не стал разбираться, коллекция ли это или обычный объект. Для него важно лишь то, что данная конструкция **не является массивом**.

P.S. - чтобы иметь возможность проверять, является ли объект массивом или нет, советую посмотреть в сторону функции [Array.isArray()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwikq675h77cAhWJkywKHa7lCMAQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fru%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FisArray&usg=AOvVaw0m3H-QznMM7JCuZ5vA2Jw1)

---

### Что делать?

Лучшим вариантом будет не полениться и все добавить руками:

```
var aPanel = [];
for (let i = 0; i < dlg.panel_s.children.length; i++)
    aPanel.push(dlg.panel_s.children[i]);
for (let i = 0; i < dlg.panel_o.children.length; i++)
    aPanel.push(dlg.panel_o.children[i]);
aPanel.push(dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u1, dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u2, dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u3);
```

---

### Другой вариант

Можете определить свой метод на уровне прототипа, который как раз и будет *разворачивать* и массивы, и коллекции до первого уровня:

```js
Array.prototype.fullConcat = function() {
    const exclude = ["string"]; // Пусть строка и является коллекцией, но мы хотим считать ее цельным объектом
    function getElements(item) { // Рекурсивно получим все элементы внутри заданного (если таковые есть)
        let result = [];
        if (item.length === undefined || exclude.includes(typeof item))
            result.push(item);
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                let add = getElements(item[i]);
                for (let j = 0; j < add.length; j++)
                    result.push(add[j]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    let concated = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { // Начнем объединение
        let item = arguments[i];
        if (item.length === undefined || exclude.includes(typeof item))
            concated.push(item);
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                let add = getElements(item[i]);
                for (let j = 0; j < add.length; j++)
                concated.push(add[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    // Не забудем и про контекст this, который может оказаться совсем не пустым
    return this.length == 0 ? concated : [].fullConcat(this, concated);
};

function testArguments() {
    return [].fullConcat(arguments, arguments);
}

// Проверим, как метод расправится со вложенностью
console.log([1, 2, 3].fullConcat([4], [5, 6, [7, 8, [9, 10]]], "hello", "world")); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "hello", "world"

// Проверим, как метод расправится с коллекцией в лице arguments
console.log(testArguments(1, 2, 3, [4, 5])); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

---

### UPD:

Большое спасибо [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) за то, что обратил мое внимание на следующий момент:

Давайте же глянем не [справку MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), а на [спецификацию ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.concat). Обратим внимание на строчки:

> 5. Repeat, while `items` is not empty
>      a. Remove the first element from items and let `E` be the value of the element.
>      b. Let `spreadable` be ? `IsConcatSpreadable(E)`.
>      c. If `spreadable` is `true`, then
>
>    ```
>       // copy items from within the object
>    ```
>
>    d. Else:
>
>    ```
>       // copy the object
>    ```

Или на русском:

> 5. Повторять, пока `items` не пуст 
>      a. Удалить первый элемент из `items`, присвоить `E` значение элемента. 
>      b. Присвоить `spreadable` значение `IsConcatSpreadable (E)`. 
>      c. Если `spreadable` является `true`, тогда
>
>    ```
>       // копировать элементы изнутри объекта
>    ```
>
>    d. Иначе:
>
>    ```
>       // копировать сам объект
>    ```

То есть за то, будет ли элемент добавлен к результирующему массиву в явном виде, или же он будет предварительно развернут как коллекция, отвечает результат выполнения некой функции [IsConcatSpreadable(O)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-isconcatspreadable). Давайте же взглянем, что это и с чем ее едят:

> 1. If `Type(O)` is not `Object`, return `false`.
> 2. Let `spreadable` be ? `Get(O, @@isConcatSpreadable)`.
> 3. If `spreadable` is not `undefined`, return `ToBoolean(spreadable)`.
> 4. Return ? `IsArray(O)`.

Или на русском:

> 1. Если `тип O` не `Object`, вернуть `false`.
> 2. Присвоить `spreadable` значение свойства `@@isConcatSpreadable` объекта `O`.
> 3. Если `spreadable` не `undefined`, вернуть `ToBoolean (spreadable)`.
> 4. Вернуть `IsArray(O)`.

То есть проверка на то, является ли объект массивом, идет в самую последнюю очередь. До этого проверяется, обладает ли объект свойством `Symbol.isConcatSpreadable`, и если он таковым обладает, то его булевое значение и будет показателем того, будет ли он раскрываться при `concat`.

Давайте теперь применим это на практике:

```js
// Создадим собственную коллекцию
var userCollection = {
0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3
};

// Убедимся, что она не является массивом
console.log(Array.isArray(userCollection)); // false

// Посмотрим, что вернет нам concat
console.log([].concat(userCollection, userCollection)); // Array [ Object(3), Object(3) ]

// Теперь маленькая хитрость:
// Установим внутреннее свойство, отвечающее
// за результат IsConcatSpreadable(O), равным true
userCollection[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = true;

// Посмотрим, что теперь вернет нам concat
console.log([].concat(userCollection, userCollection)); // Array [ "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c" ]

// Или же сразу создадим коллекцию с указанным свойством:
// Создадим собственную коллекцию
var userCollection_1 = {
0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3, [Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]: true
};

// Посмотрим, что вернет нам concat
console.log([].concat(userCollection_1, userCollection_1)); // Array [ "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c" ]
```

Работает как часы. Давайте для чистоты эксперимента проверим это на существующем перечисляемом типе. Вспомним опять же про наш [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```js
// arguments не указан, как spreadable
function nonSpreadable() {
    return [].concat(arguments, arguments);
}

// arguments указан, как spreadable
function spreadable() {
    arguments[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = true;
    return [].concat(arguments, arguments);
}

// Какой же массив вернется при объединении 2-х arguments?
console.log(nonSpreadable(1, 2)); // Array [ Arguments, Arguments ]

// А теперь?)
console.log(spreadable(1, 2));    // Array [ 1, 2, 1, 2 ]
console.log(spreadable(1, 2, 3)); // Array [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Как видите, нам удалось с помощью `concat` объединить внутренние значения `arguments` в массив

Для очистки совести напомню: лезть таким вот образом во внутренние свойства объекта, изменяя логику его работы, - **неправильно** и **кощунственно**!

Почему? Давайте представим ситуацию: Вы видите массив. Как он должен вести себя с методом `concat`? Правильно, согласно уже не раз указанной [справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) он **обязан** раскрыться при объединении! А что если кто-то с полученным Вами массивом поигрался следующим образом:

```js
// Создадим обычные массивы
var arr_0 = [1, 2];
var arr_1 = [3, 4];

// Убедимся, что это именно массивы, а не что-либо еще
console.log(Array.isArray(arr_0)); // true
console.log(Array.isArray(arr_1)); // true

// Объединим их
var arr_2 = [].concat(arr_0, arr_1);
console.log(arr_2);        // Array [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
console.log(arr_2.length); // 4, как и полагается

// А теперь сделаем парочку богопротивных действий
arr_0[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = arr_1[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = false;

// Объединим их снова
var arr_3 = [].concat(arr_0, arr_1);
console.log(arr_3);        // Array [ Array(2), Array(2) ]
console.log(arr_3.length); // 2, что-то пошло не так)
```

Только что мы изменили поведение стандартного типа, что **очень и очень неправильно**! Так что старайтесь избегать таких вот подходов!

Все, совесть очищена, так что можем злоупотреблять дальше :)

---

### Еще один вариант решения Вашей проблемы:

На основе манипулирования результатом исполнения [IsConcatSpreadable(O)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-isconcatspreadable) Вашу задачу можно решить таким вот образом:

```
// Колдуем над isConcatSpreadable:
dlg.panel_s.children[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = dlg.panel_0.children[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = true;

// Объединяем обе коллекции и три отдельных элемента
var aPanel = [].concat(
    dlg.panel_s.children, 
    dlg.panel_o.children, 
    dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u1, 
    dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u2, 
    dlg.panel_u.checkbox_u3
);
```

И живой пример для наглядности:

```js
// Сформируем свои коллекции
var userCollection_0 = {
    0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', length: 3
};
var userCollection_1 = {
    0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f', 3: 'g', length: 4
};

// Колдуем над isConcatSpreadable
userCollection_0[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = userCollection_1[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = true;

// Объединяем обе коллекции и три отдельных элемента
var aPanel = [].concat(
    userCollection_0, 
    userCollection_1, 
    'h', 
    'i', 
    'j'
);

// Посмотрим, что внутри
console.log(aPanel);        // Array [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" ]

// Убедимся, что длина также совпадает
console.log(aPanel.length); // 10 из 10)
```

---

Надеюсь, мой ответ помог Вам в разрешении проблемы! Удачи в Ваших начинаниях!

Comment: Т.о., это всё же "хитрая логика", ибо в алерте после конкатенации отображаются развёрнутые коллекции.

Comment: "Лучшим вариантом будет не полениться и все добавить руками". Так и поступил, т.к. минимум кода и используется один раз. Правда, _ExtendScript Toolkit_ ничего не знает про `let`, и пришлось объявить переменную для циклов через `var`.

Comment: @UModeL таки да) Я бы скорее даже выразился, что это хитрости приведения к строке) Ну-с, я незнаком с сиим диалектом, но он все же подчиняется стандартам ECMAScript. Странно, что `let` туда ещё не «завезли» =)

Comment: файлы с подобным диалектом имеют расширение `*.jsx` . А на англоязычном SO есть метка для таких скриптов Adobe - [extendscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extendscript) .

Comment: @UModeL, это не хитрая логика в concat, это проблема alert, что он принимает только строки, поэтому массивы и каждый их элемент приводятся к строке.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, чтобы concat Добавлял поэлементно, параметр не обязательно должен быть массивом: https://jsfiddle.net/mnsqx156/

Comment: @Grundy Вы уверены? `alert([].concat({ 0 : 1, '1' : 'а', length })[0]['1'])` -> `a`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, в комментарии выше ссылка на jsfiddle с примером.

Comment: @Grundy дописал туда `alert([].concat(t)[0]['2']);`. Получил в ответ `b` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, забавно :-) не сохранил конечную версию похоже :)

Comment: @Grundy пожалуйста: https://jsfiddle.net/kgqx890z/. В ответ идёт `b`, что свидетельствует о том, что раскрытия объекта не произошло

Comment: @Grundy бывает)

Comment: Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/mnsqx156/7/

Comment: @Grundy ого. А так можно было? ХД Не думал, что можно так схитрить, когда смотрел спецификацию хД Сейчас дополню ответ. Спасибо, интересно)

Comment: смотри в сторону [IsConcatSpreadable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-isconcatspreadable) и собственно как сам [concat](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.concat) Работает

Comment: @Grundy у меня есть ссылка на документацию в ответе (по слову стандарт), однако я про это что-то и не подумал)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80756/discussion-between-grundy-and-kir-antipov).