# Как обрезать число до n-ого знака после запятой и вернуть в виде строки?

Tags: javascript

```js
function largeDiv(a, b) {
  var result = (+a / +b)
  console.log(result);
  return
}

largeDiv("6", "2");
largeDiv("7", "3");
```

Суть задачи: заданы две строки, мы их переводим в числа, после делим друг на друга и возвращаем ответ, но:

1. Возвращаемое число должно быть в виде строки
2. Количество знаков после запятой должно быть не более 20.

Comment: Вычисления не должны производиться дальше 20-го знака, или результирующая строка должна обрезаться до 21-го?

Comment: Скорее обрезаться. В общем должно вернуть значение (строка) не дальше 20 знака. Допустим ответом будет значение 0,12903225806451611451924 .Вернуть должно только 20 знаков после нуля  0,1290322580645161451 все остальное должно просто не учитываться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function largeDiv(a, b) {
  let result = (+a / +b).toString().split(".");
  return result[0].concat(".", result[1].slice(0, 2));
}

console.log(largeDiv("5", "3"));
```

На третьей строчке вместо `2` вставьте `20`. `2` использую для наглядности, поскольку результирующая строка итак меньше 20 символов получается.

Происходит следующее.

1. Считаем результат деления, сразу же переводим его в строку методом `toString` и разделяем по точке методом `split`. В итоге в переменной `result` - массив, первый элемент которого - число до точки, второй - после.
2. `result[1].slice(0, 2)` - непосредственно укорачиваем строку после запятой до (в данном случае) двух знаков.
3. `result[0].concat(".", ...)` - соединяем число до точки (нулевой элемент массива) с уже обрезанным числом после точки (первый элемент), добавляя между ними точку в качестве разделителя.

Comment: Я кстати сразу подумывал чтобы засплитить строку, а после склеить его. Отдельное спасибо за познание метода .concat

Comment: @XAC пожалуйста! Кстати, аналогичный метод есть и у массивов.

Comment: @XAC: подробнее о `concat` - [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860866/248572))